# Groovy define an embedded json object on an embedded json object using jsonbuilder

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I want to define the following json string using jsonbuilder..

```
{
  "a":"a",
  "b":"b",
  "c":{"d":"d", 
       "e":"e", 
       "f":{"g":"g"}
      }
}
```

I can't seem to define the property f as an embedded object, this is my attempt...

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def builder = new JsonBuilder()      
builder{
    a 'a'
    b 'b'
    c(
        d: 'd',
        e: 'e',
        f:(
            g: 'g'
        )
    )
}
log.info(builder.toString())
```

I get compilation error unexpected token expected ) but got : at line 10
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong type of braces, you need:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def builder = new JsonBuilder()      
builder {
    a 'a'
    b 'b'
    c {
        d 'd'
        e 'e'
        f {
            g 'g'
        }
    }
}
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: This complained in 2.4.5

Comment: can you run against 2.4.5?

Comment: Works on 2.4.5 too :-/

Comment: Lol, I know the reason. `,` :-( yes it works. I had `d 'd', e 'e'`.... Stupid me. I am having a bad coffee right now.

Comment: Hehehe, phew! ;-)  Happens to the best of us, no worries :-D  Spent all day wondering why 2 strings weren't equal, before spotting one was in Title Case **sigh**

Comment: Totally agree, sometimes I wonder if Spock framework can watch over my shoulder to fix those kind of issues by power asserts immediately as they were written. :) On a brighter side, one good thing happened out of all the fuss is that I upgraded to Groovy 2.4.7 to test this script ;)

Comment: @user2554194 no need! That's why I'm here :-)